# How to get Google Contacts information using Google OAuth?

Tags: php, oauth

I am new to OAuth, and want to create a page that gets the user's contact list from Google using the OAuth system so they don't have to login.

How do I do this? I am using php, so I would really appreciate if there is example code that does this. I can't seem to find it on Google.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Also, are there ways to do this for Yahoo address books, etc...?

Answer (score 11):

For general OAuth principles to access Google, you might find [Google's OAuth playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/) very useful (contacts are included there).

This is a very basic example (using the php oauth pecl extension and simplexml, it just prints out the names of the 25 first contacts):

```
<?php
$cons_key="your consumer key";
$cons_sec="your consumer secret";

$callback="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$req_token_url="https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken";
$auth_token_url="https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken";
$acc_token_url="https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken";

$scope="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";
$scopes=urlencode($scope);
$req_scope_token_url=$req_token_url."?scope=".$scopes;
$endpoint="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/";

session_start();

if(!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION['state']==1) $_SESSION['state'] = 0;

try {
    $oauth = new OAuth($cons_key,$cons_sec);
    if(!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $oauth = new OAuth($cons_key,$cons_sec);
        $oauth->setRequestEngine(OAUTH_REQENGINE_CURL);
        $request_token_info = $oauth->getRequestToken($req_scope_token_url,$callback);
        if(!empty($request_token_info)) {
            $_SESSION['token']=$request_token_info['oauth_token'];
            $_SESSION['secret']=$request_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
            $_SESSION['state']=1;
            header('Location: '.$auth_token_url.'?oauth_token='.$_SESSION['token']);
            exit;
        }
    } else if($_SESSION['state']==1) {
        $oauth->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['secret']);
        $access_token_info = $oauth->getAccessToken($acc_token_url);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
    }

    $oauth->fetch($endpoint);
    parseAtom($oauth->getLastResponse());

} catch(OAuthException $E) {
    print_r($E);
}

function parseAtom($atomstring) {
    global $oauth;
    $atom=simplexml_load_string($atomstring);
    foreach ($atom->entry as $entry) {
        print $entry->title.", ";
    }
}
?>
```

You can see the above code <s>[in action here](http://futtta.be/oauth/contacts.php)</s>.

Installing (configuring) the oauth pecl extension can be tricky, you [may have to check your php.ini and/or specify a requestengine](http://blog.futtta.be/2010/08/09/php-oauth-extension-trial-error-and-succes/).

Comment: hmm, did not see this actually was an old question with a recent reply :)

Comment: there seems to be a small bug - after getting access token, the code first uses SESSION vars to set the token and only then assigns them. I think it should be in reverse - setToken should go after assignments.

Comment: absolutely stasM; I mis-copy/pasted and had "$oauth->setToken($_SESSION['token'],$_SESSION['secret']);" in there 2 times, thanks for spotting!

Comment: Hi futta, 

Can you show me where you got the OAuth class from?  

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hope my post helpful to all (Google contact list reader in PHP(Google OAuth))
http://anandafit.info/2011/03/08/google-contact-list-reader-in-php-google-oauth/

Answer (score 1):

You need to start with [Google Contacts Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html) and [OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76184/php-tutorial-for-openid-and-oauth), when you're done, [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-phpgooglecontact/index.html) should be enough for a reference.

Answer (score 1):

OK. first of all futtta i had some problems with pecl and pear stuff. so i decided to stick with ZEND. I do appreciate you posting though, your code still helped me :-)....

here is what i've got so far, taking some of the code from the ibm page posted above, but altering it to use oauth to get in.

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'common.php';
require_once 'Zend/Oauth/Consumer.php';
require_once 'Zend/Crypt/Rsa/Key/Private.php'; 

require_once 'Zend/Gdata.php';
require_once 'Zend/Gdata/Query.php';




$oauthOptions = array(
    'requestScheme'        => Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER,
    'version'              => '1.0',
    'consumerKey'          => 'PUT KEY HERE',
    'consumerSecret'       => 'PUT KEY HERE',
    'signatureMethod'      => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'requestTokenUrl'      => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken',
    'userAuthorizationUrl' => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken',
    'accessTokenUrl'       => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken'
);


?>


<!DOCTYPE html 
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Listing contacts</title>
    <style>
    body {
      font-family: Verdana;      
    }
    div.name {
      color: red; 
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bolder;  
    }
    div.entry {
      display: inline;
      float: left;
      width: 400px;
      height: 150px;
      border: 2px solid; 
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    td {
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    </style>    
  </head>
  <body>

     <?



 $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($oauthOptions); 

if (!isset($_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN_GOOGLE'])) { 
    if (!empty($_GET)) { 
        $token = $consumer->getAccessToken($_GET, unserialize($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN_GOOGLE'])); 
        $_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN_GOOGLE'] = serialize($token); 
    } else { 
        $token = $consumer->getRequestToken(array('scope'=>'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds')); 
        $_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN_GOOGLE'] = serialize($token); 
        $consumer->redirect(); 
        exit; 
    } 
} else { 
    $token = unserialize($_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN_GOOGLE']); 
    //$_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN_GOOGLE'] = null; 
} 



$http  = $token->getHttpClient($oauthOptions);
$gdata = new Zend_Gdata($http);
$gdata->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);

$gdata->getHttpClient()->setRequestScheme(Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_QUERYSTRING);


$query = new Zend_Gdata_Query('http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?);
//$query->setMaxResults(10);
$feed = $gdata->getFeed($query);

?>



      <h2><?php echo $feed->title; ?></h2>
      <div>
      <?php echo $feed->totalResults; ?> contact(s) found.
      </div>

      <?php
      // parse feed and extract contact information
      // into simpler objects
      $results = array();
      foreach($feed as $entry){
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($entry->getXML());
        $obj = new stdClass;
        $obj->name = (string) $entry->title;
        $obj->orgName = (string) $xml->organization->orgName; 
        $obj->orgTitle = (string) $xml->organization->orgTitle; 

        foreach ($xml->email as $e) {
          $obj->emailAddress[] = (string) $e['address'];
        }

        foreach ($xml->phoneNumber as $p) {
          $obj->phoneNumber[] = (string) $p;
        }
        foreach ($xml->website as $w) {
          $obj->website[] = (string) $w['href'];
        }

        $results[] = $obj;  
      }


    ?>

    <?php
    // display results
    foreach ($results as $r) {
    ?>
    <div class="entry">
      <div class="name"><?php echo (!empty($r->name)) ? 
       $r->name : 'Name not available'; ?></div>
      <div class="data">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Organization</td>
            <td><?php echo $r->orgName; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><?php echo @join(', ', $r->emailAddress); ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td><?php echo @join(', ', $r->phoneNumber); ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Web</td>
            <td><?php echo @join(', ', $r->website); ?></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

There are still some problems, for me it only posts 25 results and i cannot seem to get setmaxresults to work... there seems to be problems with ZEND for that... if someone knows a work around, please post.

b

Answer (score 1):

Comment out the setRequestScheme method call and use max-results and you should be able to get more than 25 entries.

```
//$gdata->getHttpClient()->setRequestScheme(Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_QUERYSTRING);

$query = new Zend_Gdata_Query('http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/?max-results=999999');
```