# Using Gdata authorization by removing hardcoded gmail credentials to get google contacts

Tags: api, contacts, gdata

***The idea is to login through gmail and get all contacts details and also add a contact from PHP code to google contact list.
The whole flow is working well and i am getting contact list and also adding contacts with fields.
The problem is that the code has hardcoded variables where i need to set google email and password.I want to have a link to authoriZe and then get all response..
So i just need to bypass the credentials on first attempt using an API or token method and get the contact details***

Please suggest if someone has gone through this issue or share examples or resourced that might help toward the solution.

Here is the code snippet...

```
$user = "XXX@XXX.com";
$pass = "XXX";
```

// Need to remove above 2 lines and combine the login on the fly API using some  with further working stuff

```
try {
      // perform login and set protocol version to 3.0
      $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
      $user, $pass, 'cp');
```

$gdata = new Zend_Gdata($client);
      $gdata->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);

```
  // perform query and get feed of all results
  $query = new Zend_Gdata_Query(
    'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full');
  $query->maxResults = 1000;
  $query->setParam('orderby', 'lastmodified');
  $query->setParam('sortorder', 'descending');
  $feed = $gdata->getFeed($query);
```

//display data in loop below....
    }

Basically I want to remove the `user` and `pwd` variables and do it on the fly to get data.
Right now I am getting all contacts and also able to add a contact but the way of setting credentials is to be changed to be more secure using a token or other way..

Answer (score 1):

Insead of using the username and password directly, you need to use the Google OAuth. You need to first create a project in the Google OAuth and specify correct details. Using the app created there, you can ask for permission of a user and get his contact details in the response.

[How to get Google Contacts information using Google OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706407/how-to-get-google-contacts-information-using-google-oauth)

Comment: I trie that by keys and updating oauth method.the flow stops before feed generates result.